# Apache Camel Integration with Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-camel, elasticsearch-plugin

I'm working on a project using Apache Camel and Elasticsearch and I was wondering which version of Elasticsearch does Camel support?

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-xmljson</artifactId>
  <version>2.18.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>xom</groupId>
  <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

But when I want to route a file to elasticsearch, I've got the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]

I found that this exception is due to a node or a TransportClient using an old version. So I try to add the elasticsearch dependency :

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>5.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

But it gives me a new error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/WriteConsistencyLevel

So I'm wondering.. Which version of ES can I use with Apache Camel?

The code for trying to send data to elasticsearch:

```
XmlJsonDataFormat xmlJsonFormat = new XmlJsonDataFormat();

from("file://C:/Projects/?fileName=data.xml&charset=utf-8")
    .marshal(xmlJsonFormat)
    .to("elasticsearch://clusterES?transportAddresses=127.0.0.1:9300&operation=BULK_INDEX&indexName=xml&indexType=account");
```

Comment: Solved the problem by using an ES server 2.4.3!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to add any other pom except the camel-elasticsearch. It seems more likely that you have a TransportClient running on an older version. You need to find it and upgrade the TransportClient.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_transport_client_versus_node_client.html

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/received-message-from-unsupported-version-2-0-0-minimal-compatible-version-is-5-0-0/64708

Comment: From a quick look at the camel repository I can see that there are two elasticsearch modules *camel-elasticsearch* and *camel-elasticsearch5*. It might be as easy as replacing your dependency. That being said, the elasticsearch node client is very sensible to version differences, even minor ones, so it might still not work. If there is an option to use the http transport instead that would be far more robust.